# How to workaround 0x01 invalid character exception. Using Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, invalid-characters

Im trying to parse a folder with a bunch of xml files. The xml files contains information about some vehicles. The XML files are autogenerated and i some of them has invalid characters. The thing is that, there are too many files for me to correct them manually. So i wonder how i can bypass the invalid character exception? 
This is the invalid line in some of the xml files:

```
<ECU EcuName="ABS" EcuFamily="BSS" CplNo="&#01;" Address="0x0B" ConfigChecksum="0x00000000" Updated="false">
```

I have tried to use Streamreader without any success. This is my code:

```
 XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StreamReader((path), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")));                
            var nameValues =
                from fpc in docs.Descendants("FPC")
                select new
                {
                    Name = (string)fpc.Attribute("Name"),
                    Value = (string)fpc.Attribute("Value")
                };
```

Comment: What created the files to start with? It would be best to fix that.

Comment: The file are being created by different software updaters when the update the vehicle. The xml files contains autogenerated information regarding the vehicle which is generated by another program which i have no control over. @JonSkeet

Comment: That's awkward. You could read each file in and replace `&#01;` with an empty string, for example... is that the only invalid character, and the only format in which it occurs?

Comment: I know, The thing is that the xml file is a read only file. So i can't change anything in them. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to you can load the file with e.g.

```
XDocument doc;
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path, new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false }))
{
  doc = XDocument.Load(xr);
}
// now query document here
```

That will get by character references like the one you have shown, not by disallowed literal characters however.

Comment: How can i allow all characters??

Comment: You can't, not with XML parsers, as the XML spec defines the allowed characters and a control character other than tab, newline or carriage return is not allowed. Basically your input is not well-formed XML.